# Command Prompt: Check whether windows service is started or not

Tags: oracle, command-line, windows-services, oracle10g

I have a batch file that executes a `.sql` file to backup a database. I put my batch file into startup folder to backup database when computer turns on. But Oracle server is not started when this batch file trying to run. So I can't backup database.

So I want to check whether Oracle server is started or not using batch file. If Oracle server is started, then batch file runs the command to execute a `.sql` file to backup database. Else it should wait till Oracle server start. When Oracle server started, batch file should run the command to execute a `.sql` file to backup database.

How could I do this?

Comment: Maybe time to upgrade to PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your Oracle service is local, you can use [`sc start`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx)

```
start /wait sc start <name-of-your-oracle-service>
```

If the service is started, this command will return right away. Otherwise, it will wait for the service start-up to complete before returning.

If a service name contains spaces, enclose the name in double quotation marks `"`.

Comment: how to wait some seconds if service is not started ? (i'm using windows xp)

Comment: @Bishan I edited the answer to use a more "modern" mechanism of starting/stopping the service on XP, and added a wait command so that you wouldn't have to do anything else in your batch file.

Comment: nice, i didn't know you could do that! @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can check if network service by using "sc query" command, before running your backup database commands. Alternately, you can also execute the following ping command to delay starting your process,

```
ping -n 5 localhost > NUL
```